# Capturing the desktop in real time and analyzing with openCV

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I'm currently working on a project that needs to analyze the colors on your monitor. My solution so far is to use (in python) pyscreengrab and colorthief. This is slow, and I'd like it to be as real time as possible. How do i capture the desktop session and analyze the frames?

Running ubuntu 17.04, and I'd like to use C/C++ for the final product.

Comment: Check `cnee` out - it can record/replay/broadcast X11 data in real time. Whether that includes actual pixel colors I don't know...

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll have a proper look into cnee later

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use pure [OpenCV](https://opencv.org), the bonus is that it has a lot of high-performance image analysis algorithms, or if you want to stay with python, give a look at [MSS](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mss/), according to them it is fast, a bonus is that it is multi-platform.

Comment: How would you go about it in pure openCV? I've considered using ffmpeg to stream, but I feel like that's a silly way if going about it.

Comment: I would work directly in C++ and use only OpenCV to process the image data, you can use things like MIT's shared memory extension for X to capture the screen, in some cases (small rectangles), you can get much more than 1000 fps. But I'm not sure what your needs are. Maybe MSS will be quick enough for you, maybe OpenCV may be too much and only a low level capture and very basic analysis is enough?

Comment: I've found a way to capture at about 200fps using MSS. The analysis is very slow though.

Comment: Sorry for the long time. In this case, maybe you should consider using also a performance-focused image analysis library too (as I pointed, openCV), you can stay with python if needed (OpenCV-Python may be of good use),  I can't be more precise as I have no clue of what kind of analysis you're doing. Also be aware that python threads are not good for concurrency as they are serialized by the global interpreter lock.